# scala lift add a templated snippet inside a wizard

Tags: scala, lift, wizard

Im currently doing a project using lift screens and wizards. 
I need to add a table inside my flow. I couldn't find a way of creating a table inside my wizard.

Is there any way of creating a table inside a wizard or adding an external template snippet as a screen of a wizard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your table can go at either the top or bottom of the screen, you can override `screenTop` or `screenBottom` to insert your table appropriately.

```
override def screenTop = Full(<lift:YourTableSnippet/>)
```

If you need the table to go into the middle of the screen, that's a bit more complicated.  You could try creating a custom `Field`, but I doubt that's going to render exactly the way you want.

```
val table = new Field {
  type ValueType = Unit

  def name = S ? "table.name"

  def default = ()

  implicit def manifest = buildIt[Unit]

  override def toForm = Full(<lift:YourTableSnippet/>)
}
```

Comment: that seems a good way, but it will render only in the right part of the page, doesn't it. i mean in the widget area rather than name area. I'll try to override the css anyway. thanks